# How does length change with volume for a cube, and what is the rate of change of length at a particular volume?

Tags: calculus

The rate at which the volume of a cube increases is $3.5cm^3s^{-1}$

What is the rate at which the length of one side of the cube increases if the volume is $200cm^3$?

I started with $dV/dt =3.5$ and I know that the volume of a cube increases by a cubic factor with relation to the sides. So if a 2x2x2 cube is increased t 4x4x4, the volume doesn't double, it cubes...

But I'm not sure what to do with this information?

Also, how do I find the volume of the cube, given that at that volume, a side increases at a rate if $2mms^{-1}$

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you done implicit differentiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the formula $V=a^3$, where $a$ is the lenght of the side of the cube. Differentiating with respect to the time $t$ we get

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = 3a^2\frac{da}{dt}$$

When the volume is $200cm^3$, we have $a=\sqrt[3]{200}$, so substituting in the equation above we get

$$3.5 = 3\cdot(200)^{\frac{2}{3}}\frac{da}{dt}$$

Now solve for $\frac{da}{dt}$ and you're done. For your other question, the only difference is that you now know the value of $\frac{da}{dt}$ and will solve for $\frac{dV}{dt}$ in the end.